# Integrating R in gedit

Tags: r, gedit

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise), Gedit-3.4.1, R-2.15.2, rgedit
v0.8.0.1-Gtk3 plugin

I am following instructions from [here](http://www.stattler.com/article/using-gedit-or-rgedit-r)

latest release of rgedit v0.8.0.1-Gtk3(16 January 2013),don't have below
files

- RCtrl.gedit-plugin
- RCtrl.preferences

but it have RCtrl.plugin file instead of RCtrl.gedit-plugin.

I extract content of rgedit v0.8.0.1-Gtk3  to /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
& enable "R integration" plugin from edit>preferences>plugin
in main menu "R" is appeared,

but when I click on "configure R interface",doesn't show configuration
panel.

even I click on other option,no activity is showing ?

Should I rename RCtrl.plugin file to RCtrl.gedit-plugin & use it ?

& which version should I use ? rgedit v0.8.0.1-Gtk3 or rgedit v0.8.0.1-Gtk2

What will be the problem ?

Comment: @neilfws , gedit has great plugin for syntax highlighting for many languages,I can use python terminal at the same time,it comes with every debian OS,can customized in many way,freely available & mostly used by people who just learn programming

Answer (score 1):

Your Gedit is version 3.X. To install, extract the `rgedit-X.X.X.X-Gtk3.tar.bz2` plugin archive file somewhere and copy the contents of the resulting folder into to your `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`. If the `plugins` folder does not exist, just create it.

After install, you need to run Gedit and select "Preferences" from the "Edit" menu. Then on the plugins tab, check the box "R integration". This will open an R console at the base of Gedit and load R.